# The upper Fell topology on Hyperspaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $2^X$ be the set of closed subsets of $X$. For every subset $A \subset X$, we define: $A^+=\{ F \in 2^X ; F \subset A \}$. Let, $\Delta$, be the set of finite subsets of $X$. Then the upper fell topology, is the topology whose base is the collection $\{({D^c})^+;D \in \Delta\} \cup 2^X$.

My question is: $X$ is a closed subset of itself. So, how will a neighborhood of $X \in 2^X$ look like. It has to containe all finite sets $F$ of $X$, in which $X \subset F^c$. But, there is no finite set that satisfies that. So, are there any open neighborhoods of $X$ exapt the point $X$ itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have noticed, if $D \in \Delta$ is such that $$X \in ( D^{\text{c}} )^+ = ( X \setminus D )^+ = \{ F \in 2^X : F \subseteq X \setminus D \},$$ then $D = \varnothing$.  Furthermore, an easy calculation yields$$(\varnothing^\text{c} )^+ = \{ F \in 2^X : F \subseteq \varnothing^\text{c} = X \} = 2^X,$$ and so $2^X$ is the only open neighbourhood of $X$ in the upper Fell topology.